# Solaris (novel, 2011 English translation) Why were the automats locked up?

Tags: aliens, robots, space-exploration, stanislaw-lem

In the novel 'Solaris', by Stanslaw Lem, Kris Kelvin notices that the automats are all missing after he arrives on Solaris Station.  He questions Snaut about this, but the latter refuses to explain.

It's soon revealed that

> The Ocean is manifesting people from the crew's memories, and Snaut can't explain it to Kelvin because he knows that Kelvin will think he's insane.  Instead, he has to wait for Kelvin to experience it for himself.

However, Snaut and Kelvin have laid their cards on the table by the end of the book but, as far as I can tell, it's never explained why all the automats were hidden away.  Given what we learn about the situation on the station, I can't think of any reason why the little helper bots would be a problem for Snaut or Sartorious.

Did I miss some clue, or was this just never explained?  I can barely find a mention of the Solaris automats in Google searches, aside from direct quotes from the novel.

I am working off the 2011 English translation audio book.

Comment: They don't appear to make an appearance in the 1961 reprint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My translation is slightly different from yours - in mine, the "automats" are referred to as "robots" (and the character named "Snaut" in yours is named "Snow" in mine; there are probably more differences). But the automats/robots being locked away is never directly explained. My best guess is that it fits in with the general air of paranoia. By locking away the station's internal automats/robots the crew ensures that anything *else* moving around the station has to be a Visitor.

In chapter 1, Kelvin and Snaut/Snow have this conversation:

> [Snaut/Snow] “Wait!” He had an uneasy look, as if he wanted to add something but
>   was finding it difficult to bring out the words. After a pause, he
>   said:
>  “There used to be three of us here. Now, with you, there are
>   three of us again. Do you know Sartorius?”
>  [Kelvin] “In the same way as I
>   knew you—only from his photographs.”
>  [Snaut/Snow] “He’s up there, in the
>   laboratory, and I doubt if he’ll come down before dark, but… In any
>   case, you’ll recognize him. **If you should see anyone else—someone
>   who isn’t me or Sartorius, you understand, then…”**

Comment: That's a good point, and is certainly in-character for a pair of scientists trying to tackle a strange problem.  I'll wait 24 hours to see if anyone else has a more concrete answer; if not, I'll mark this as the answer.